# Cannot get data in INPUT_GET in php

Tags: php, get

I am using the RESTful webservice for my application. In that I cant able to get the data in INPUT_GET.

eg.

```
$courseYear = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'CourseYear', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
var_dump($courseYear); //null
```

I gave the GET method body value as `CourseYear=2005-2007`

Please help me to get the value.

Comment: What does `print_r($_GET)` give you?

Comment: @chris85 It gives empty `Array
(
)`

Comment: Okay, so your GET isn't populated. How are you sending the data to this page? Do you see the parameters in the URL?

Comment: I'm sending the data using rest client body parameters

Comment: Sending or receiving? `INPUT_GET` is looking for a `GET` parameter.

Comment: INPUT_GET is looking for GET method and parameter CourseYear=2005_-_2007

Comment: I var_dump($courseYear) but it returns NULL.

Comment: Yes, your `$_GET` is empty so the way your accessing this has no `GET` or it is being stripped on a redirect.

Comment: Maybe, that might the reason. so whats the solution.

Comment: Send the `GET` parameter. Load your URL with `?CourseYear=2005_-_2007`

Comment: How to send along with auth token

Comment: I don't know what you mean `send` your looking at input here

Comment: @chris85 thanks for your suport